# Dynamic Linq Library Guid exceptions

Tags: entity-framework, dynamicquery

I am having a problem with the Dynamic Linq Library. I get a the following error "ParserException was unhandled by user code ')" or ','". I have a Dicitionary and I want to create a query based on this dictionary. So I loop through my dictionary and append to a string builder "PersonId = (GUID FROM DICTIONARY). I think the problem is were I append to PersonId for some reason I can't seem to convert my string guid to a Guid so the dynamic library don't crash.

I have tried this to convert my string guid to a guid, but no luck.

```
query.Append("(PersonId = Guid(" + person.Key + ")");

query.Append("(PersonId = " + person.Key + ")");
```

I am using VS 2010 RTM and RIA Services as well as the Entity Framework 4.

```
//This is the loop I use
foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, PersonDetails> person in personsDetails)
{
    if ((person.Value as PersonDetails).IsExchangeChecked)
    {
        query.Append("(PersonId = Guid.Parse(" + person.Key + ")");
    }
}

//Domain service call
 var query = this.ObjectContext.Persons.Where(DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<Person, bool>(persons));
```

Please help, and if you know of a better way of doing this I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a parameterized query, e.g.:

```
var query = this.ObjectContext.Persons.Where(
     "PersonId = @1", new [] { person.Key } );
```

Comment: This in ancient, but `@1` should be `@0` (they are zero-indexed)

Answer (score 5):

For GUID comparison with dynamic linq use query properties and the Equals() method like in the provided sample.

```
var items = new[]
            {
                new { Id = Guid.Empty },
                new { Id = Guid.NewGuid() },
                new { Id = Guid.NewGuid() },
                new { Id = Guid.NewGuid() }
            };

var result = items.AsQueryable()
    .Where("Id.Equals(@0)", Guid.Empty)
    .Any();
```

Comment: Confirmed worked with EntityFramework 6.1 also (versions matter with EF lol )

Answer (score 1):

Did you try(notice the extra ')' ).

```
   query.Append("(PersonId = Guid(" + person.Key + "))");
```